# verify password yii framework

Tags: php, authentication, yii

In model BaseUser.php, I have define `$verifyPassword` and add it in rules

```
public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('name, email, phone_code, phone, country, language, password, role, status', 'required'),
            array('verifyPassword','required', 'on'=>'insert'),
            array('country, role, status, payment', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('name, email, active_key', 'length', 'max'=>50),
            array('phone_code', 'length', 'max'=>5),
            array('phone', 'length', 'max'=>30),
            array('language', 'length', 'max'=>10),
            array('password', 'length', 'max'=>32),
            array('verifyPassword', 'length', 'max'=>32),
            array('device_token, token', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('created', 'safe'),
            array('country', 'haveToSelect'),
            array('email', 'unique', 'message' => Yii::t('app',"This user's email adress already exists.")),
            array('verifyPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password'),
            array('device_token, active_key, token, payment, created', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
            array('id, name, email, phone_code, phone, country, language, password, role, device_token, active_key, status, token, payment, created', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

In ProfileController.php

```
public function actionIndex()
    {  

        $data = Yii::app()->session['Authentication'];
        $idUserLogin = $data->id;

        $dataUser = Users::model()->findByPk($idUserLogin);

        if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
            $dataUser->setAttributes($_POST['Users']);

            if($dataUser->save()) {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success',Yii::t('app','Change profile successful!'));
                $this->refresh();
            }
        }
```

I register a new account successful but in another function which use profile'user... I can't save after change it.

For example, in function change profile when press Save button... nothing change... nothing alert... nothing notification of validate.

How do I resolve that problem?

Comment: It sounds like on update something is failing in terms of validation. 
Can you provide me the results of a:  echo '<pre>'.print_r($dataUser,true).'</pre>';  after this line: $dataUser->setAttributes($_POST['Users']); when you're trying to do an update?

Comment: thank you... I sloved that problem.. :)

Comment: Is this question solved? If that was the solution then post it yourself and accept as the answer, or just delete the question, but it could help people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved that problem...

I changed rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('name, email, phone_code, phone, country, language, password, role, status', 'required'),
        array('verifyPassword','required', 'on'=>'register'),
        array('country, role, status, payment', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('name, email, active_key', 'length', 'max'=>50),
        array('phone_code', 'length', 'max'=>5),
        array('checkAgree', 'required', 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'You must have to agree with...', 'on'=>'register'),
        array('phone', 'length', 'max'=>30),
        array('language', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        array('password', 'length', 'max'=>32),
        array('verifyPassword', 'length', 'max'=>32),
        array('device_token, token', 'length', 'max'=>100),
        array('created', 'safe'),
        array('country', 'haveToSelect'),
        array('email', 'unique', 'message' => Yii::t('app',"This user's email adress already exists.")),
        array('verifyPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'on'=>'register'),
        array('device_token, active_key, token, payment, created', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
        array('id, name, email, phone_code, phone, country, language, password, role, device_token, active_key, status, token, payment, created', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

I check 'verifyPassword' on register scenario

and in my controller i define:

```
$user = new User('register')
```